# How to join each item in a list with "and" operator

Tags: python, list

I need to select each item in a list and put and logical operator in between each item

e.g

say if I have a list:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
```

and I want:

```
'a' and 'b' and 'c'
```

Comment: Did you try the `join` method?

Comment: Do you really want quotes in the result, not `a and b and c`?

Comment: join method doesn't work on logical operator when I tried

Comment: yes I need to keep 'a' 'b' 'c' as string

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import and_
from functools import reduce
reduce(and_, ['a' , 'b' , 'c'], True)
```

and yes, this does not work with chars

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `all` function pretty much what you are trying to do?

```
a = ['a','b','c']
all(a)
```